# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <RouterView> (with plugin:vue/recommended eslint rules)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, eslint

I recently started linting my Vue CLI 3 project with `plugin:vue/recommended` eslint plugin.

One of the rules is `vue/component-name-in-template-casing` with the default being PascalCase, but when `<router-view />` is autofixed to `<RouterView />` I get a runtime error:

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <RouterView> - did you register the component correctly?`

I (think I) do like the pascal-cased names better; how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using vue-router v3.0.2+.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue-router": "^3.0.2"
}
```

---

The differences can be seen in the `install.js` file...

[Version 3.0.1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/v3.0.1/src/install.js#L46) (and before) has...

> ```
> Vue.component('router-view', View)
> ```

Whereas [version 3.0.2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/v3.0.2/src/install.js#L46) changed it to

> ```
> Vue.component('RouterView', View)
> ```

The problem with the older format is that it explicitly registers only the `<router-view>` component whereas the latest version is able to handle either kebab or Pascal cased component names in your templates.

---

From the [v3.0.2 release notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/releases/tag/v3.0.2)...

> RouterLink and RouterView can now be used in PascalCase ([#1842](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/1842))